# Broken Language Encoding

Tags: visual-studio, file, encoding, utf-8

I have some C/C++ files from Visual Studio 2015 that have Korean comments on them. I zipped the solution, uploaded it to Google Drive, downloaded it on a different computer, downloaded the Korean language pack, but even then the comments are all broken. Some sort of encoding problem?

For example:
// ¸î°¡Áö ¸í½ÉÇØ¾ßÇÒ ÇÁ·Î±×·¡¹ÖÀÇ ±âº»¿ø¸®
// Ã¹¹øÂ°. ÇÁ·Î±×·¡¹Ö¿¡¼­ ¸ðµç°ÍÀº ¼ýÀÚ(0, 1)·Î¸¸ ÀÏ·ç¾îÁ® ÀÖ´Ù.

Maybe I need to change the encoding from UTF-8 to something else, but I don't know how to do that. Is there any way I could get the comments to show up properly again? Thank you!

Comment: Did you do a binary compare with your original file and the one you downloaded?  If so, are they equal?  If so, then it's something local on your machine.  If not equal, then your file's comments get munged up somewhere during initial upload and download.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i'm sorry how do you do a binary compare for different files?

Comment: Get any comparison tool that compares file contents.  You will need to get one that does a binary compare instead of comparing just text.  The files should be exactly the same in terms of each and every byte.  If whole sections of the files are different, than something got messed up in the zipping, uploading, downloading, or unzipping.  Having said this, this isn't really a C++ issue, but a file maintenance one.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry, I'm not too well-versed in this area.Thank you so much!